# GEF: How to add figures to different BorderLayout sections of RootEditPart/-Figure

Tags: eclipse-plugin, visualization, layout-manager, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I have a GEF Editor with the following `RootEditPart`.

```
public class MyProjectEditPart extends AbstractGraphicalEditPart {

@Override
protected IFigure createFigure() {
    ScalableFreeformLayeredPane layer = new ScalableFreeformLayeredPane();
    layer.setLayoutManager(new FreeformLayout());
    return layer;
  }
```

I'm using the editor to create a bottom-up tree:

```
     _7_
    /   \
   5     6
  / \   / \
 1   2 3   4
```

`1-7` are `Rectangle`s, where `1-4` represent different model elements than `5-7`. At the moment, all figures are laid out by foot (`new Rectangle(x, y, w, h)` + `parent.setConstraint(this, figure, rectangle)`). The position of figures `5-7` is calculated with a simple algorithm, based on the position on figures `1-4`.

For the sake of practicality I'd like to be able to simply add `1-4` to a `FlowLayout`ed `Figure` at the `BorderLayout.BOTTOM` of the RootFigure, and add the rest of the figures to the RootFigure's `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

However, I'm pretty new to GEF and can't get my head around how to do it. I fail to find the right method for adding the figures `1-4` in their respective `EditPart`'s `createFigure()`.

For example, I've tried stuff like `parent.getFigure().getChildren().get(0).add(Figure_1)` for example, with the RootEditPart's `createFigure()` method adding two new figures to `BorderLayout.BOTTOM` and `CENTER` respectively..

I'd be thankful for any starting points :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an EditPartFactory which "dispatches" the model elements to different EditParts.
The toplevel editpart (7) should then implement getModelChildren to return the 5 and 6, whose editparts in turn should return as children the 1,2 and 3,4.

How about taking some time the GEF shape example and/or with http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246302.html ?